# Google Suggest API : make a query with a prefix

Tags: google-suggest

I am playing with http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search to make some google suggest queries.

It works fine with "mykeyword" & "mykeyword a" or "mykeyword b". I got good results.

But I would like to make some queries with a prefix, eg : "a mykeyword" in order to get some suggests that start with a 'a" & contains "mykeywords. It works on the google page but not via the API

Any suggestions?

Comment: have find issue ? @user3142926

Answer (score 0):

To separate words use `%20` or `+` between them. For `a mykeyword`:

http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=en&q=a%20mykeyword

or

http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=en&q=a+mykeyword